# Call android frescolib BaseControllerListener.onFailure more the one time

Tags: java, android, fresco

I have a dummy app. It show an image in main activity. 
I have a bunch of urls to this image with different resolution. 
Some times urls can be broken and app should load image from another url.

[Listening to Events](http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-to-events.html)
I figured out, that ControllerListener is my best bet to handle this issue.

But i have a small trouble:
Suppose i have 3 urls and first 2 of them is broken. onFailure won't call twice or more times and i can't reach to the proper url... so that's why i'm here.
Any suggestions?

May be in onFailure i should knock all my urls with retrofit and get first accessable link?

```
public class CustomControllerListener<DataType> 
    extends BaseControllerListener<ImageInfo> {

private SimpleDraweeView sdvPoster;
public List<String> urls;
private int tryCount = 0;

@Override
public void onFailure(String id, Throwable throwable) {
    sdvPoster.setUri(urls.get(tryCount));
    tryCount++;
}
```

}

```
CustomControllerListener controllerListener = new CustomControllerListener();
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add("example.com/gol.png");
urls.add("example.com/fol.png");
urls.add("example.com/dol.png");
urls.add(value);
controllerListener.urls = urls;
DraweeController draweeController = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder()
                .setUri("example.com/lol.png")
                .setControllerListener(controllerListener)
                .build();
sdwPoster.setController(draweeController);
```

Well, i'm ended up with my own suggestion: "May be in onFailure i should knock all my urls with retrofit and get first accessable link?"

It's work perfect for me. But i'm curious, is there a better solution?

From the docs i'm figured out, that **setTapToRetryEnabled(true)** allows calling **onFailure** multiple times (var tryCount increments every time, when im touch view). but when i'm trying to attach new url to the view, **ControllerListener** stops working.

Comment: post your current codes.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Controller and ImageRequest in onFailure:

```
ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(newUri) 
.build(); 

DraweeController draweeController2 = Fresco.newDraweeControllerBuilder() 
.setUri(newUri).setImageRequest(imageRequest).build(); 

imageView.setController(draweeController2);
```

Your calling class, listening for the onFailure event, could provide newUri

from [this comment on github](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/issues/1693)